# Entity Framework core6 Scaffold-DbContext for .NET 6 nullable properties

Tags: .net, entity-framework-core, reverse-engineering, nullable, ef-core-6.0

I recently upgraded to Visual Studio 2022 and .NET 6 and Entity Framework Core 6 (v.6.0.3).  I ran the Scaffold-DbContext command in the Package Manager Console to reverse engineer a database:

```
Scaffold-DbContext "Data Source=MUFASA;Initial Catalog=VerityLearnDB2;Integrated Security=True" Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -Context VerityContext -ContextDir DataAccess -OutputDir Model
```

There are issues in this version of .NET regarding nullable references and properties that are affecting the output from the reverse engineering process.  I have several tables with nullable columns like:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[AnswerOptions](
    [OptionId] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [OptionText] [nvarchar](255) NOT NULL,
    [IsCorrect] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [Rationale] [nvarchar](max) NOT NULL,
    [QuestionId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [OptionImage] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [RationaleImage] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_AnswerOptions] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [OptionId] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
```

This generates an AnswerOption class,

```
    public partial class AnswerOption
    {
        public AnswerOption()
        {
            AssocCourseTopics = new HashSet<AssocCourseTopic>();
            UserExamOptions = new HashSet<UserExamOption>();
            Topics = new HashSet<Topic>();
        }

        public int OptionId { get; set; }
        public string OptionText { get; set; } = null!;
        public bool? IsCorrect { get; set; }
        public string Rationale { get; set; } = null!;
        public int QuestionId { get; set; }
        public string? OptionImage { get; set; }
        public string? RationaleImage { get; set; }

        public virtual Question Question { get; set; } = null!;
        public virtual ICollection<AssocCourseTopic> AssocCourseTopics { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<UserExamOption> UserExamOptions { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Topic> Topics { get; set; }
    }
```

This produces a warning message for all nullable properties,

```
"Warning    CS8632  The annotation for nullable reference types should only be used in code within a '#nullable' annotations context.   VerityLearn.Console L:\Projects\Tutoring\VerityLearning\VerityInitSolution9\VerityLearn.Console\Model\AnswerOption.cs"
```

I have placed a "disable" line in the .csproj file.  However, I have to go through all the Model files and place a line "#nullable enable" to remove the warning and avoid, potentially, other problems.

For a database with a large number of files this is a large task.

Does anyone have any viable suggestions on how to work around this?

Thank you.

Comment: Create a seperate project for the EF Core generated code, and set nullable enable

Comment: I try this at some point.  Seems logical.  I'm hip-deep in pushing something out the door.  This current work is internal only, but later I need to be able to do something like this.  BTW, what do you think about EF Core Powertools for reverse engineering?

Comment: Highly recommended (I created it) 

Comment: This looks like a bug. If `nullable` isn't enabled in the .csproj, it's shouldn't scaffold nullable reference types. Can you [submit a new issue](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/new/choose) with a repro attached so we can investigate?

Comment: Actually, nullable IS enabled in the .csproj and I place a "#nullable enable" line in the Model classes after using the EF Power Tools to scaffold.  I still get warnings, but so far, I have not encountered problems.  I'm, also, using JSON serialization on retrieved data with some cyclic reference issues.